Representation of isometry of Hilbert spaces with orthonormal basis
On P61 of Lax's Functional Analysis:

I'll type it out:

Let $H$ denote a Hilbert space, $\{x_j\}$ and $\{y_j\}$ two orthonormal bases.
Every $x\in H$ can be written as
$$x = \sum a_j x_j,\quad a_j = \langle x,x_j\rangle$$
Then the mapping
$$x\to y = \sum a_j y_j$$
is an isometry of $H$ onto $H$, mapping $0$ to $0$.
Furthermore every isometry of $H$ onto $H$ mapping $0$ to $0$
can be obtained in this fashion.

After struggling with the proof,
I believe the last statement doesn't hold for complex Hilbert spaces.
(Judging from the context, I think Lax would've stated it explicitly
if the result only holds for real Hilbert spaces.)
I've found a counterexample:
$$f:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^2$$
$$f(x,y) = (\operatorname{Re}x + i\operatorname{Im} y, 
\operatorname{Re}y + i\operatorname{Im} x)$$
Could someone tell me if I've made a mistake here,
or is this an error in the book? Thanks!

I agree with you. I didn't check your counterexample, but a simpler one is$$\Bbb C\to\Bbb C,\;z\mapsto\overline z.$$
See also Mazur-Ulam-like theorem for complex Hilbert spaces.

Thank you! This counterexample is elegant. Actually I came up with my ugly example when I tried to prove the theorem after generalizing the mapping to $$x\to y = \sum a_j y_j + \sum \overline{a_j}y_j,$$ i.e. partly linear and partly conjugate linear.
